# Search Controller move along tableview

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller

code of search controller

it's working fine for searching

issue 1:

when I scroll tableView, I want to show search controller along with table view, search controller also gets scrolled with table view.

```
 let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)

  override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
          searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self

        searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false

        searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false

        tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar

        searchController.delegate = self

        searchController.searchBar.sizeToFit()


        self.searchController.searchBar.delegate = self

        tableView.tableHeaderView = nil

        definesPresentationContext = true
}
```

update data of searching  :

```
func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {


        _ = kidsData

        let searchToSearch = searchController.searchBar.text

        if(searchToSearch == "")
        {
            self.kidsData = self.KidsDataDuplicate

        }
        else{

            self.kidsData.removeAll()

            let itemsarray = self.KidsDataDuplicate

            var forkidsinArray = [String]()

            for Kids in itemsarray {

                forkidsinArray.append(Kids.name)
                if(Kids.name.range(of: searchToSearch!, options: .caseInsensitive) != nil)
                {
                    self.kidsData.append(Kids)

                }

            }
          }

        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
```

issue 2 :

`Tableview navigation bar` contains *search button*, when I click on *search button* at `navigation bar`, search controller should show its working at tableview header, but after scrolling tableview I want to show search controller at tableview starting cell. 
 I can try the scroll delegates it's not working for me
 pls help me......!

this is code of *search button* at navigation

```
var launchBool: Bool = false {
    didSet {
        if launchBool == true {

            Status = 1
            tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar
                   let indexPath = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)
               self.tableView.scrollToRow(at: indexPath, at: .middle, animated: true)


        } else {

               tableView.tableHeaderView = nil
               myInt = 0

        }
    }
}


 @IBAction func NAVSearchButton(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
       launchBool = !launchBool


    }
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, for your first part, you can have a look at how searchBar and searchBarController are used 
https://grokswift.com/swift-tableview-search-bar/

Comment: next view controller does not have navigation controller I did programmatically how to add the scroll bar.